# Wordpress remove white spaces

Tags: php, wordpress

I've this code which runs the excerpt outside the loop in wordpress.

```
<?php
function get_excerpt_by_id($post_id){
$the_post = get_post($post_id); //Gets post ID
$the_excerpt = $the_post->post_content; //Gets post_content to be used as a basis for the excerpt
$excerpt_length = 35; //Sets excerpt length by word count
$the_excerpt = strip_tags(strip_shortcodes($the_excerpt)); //Strips tags and images
$words = explode(' ', $the_excerpt, $excerpt_length + 1);
if(count($words) > $excerpt_length) :
array_pop($words);
array_push($words, '…');
$the_excerpt = implode(' ', $words);
endif;
$the_excerpt = '<p>' . $the_excerpt . '</p>';
return $the_excerpt;
}
?>
```

As you can see it removes all the content like images and other stuff and leaves only the text, but when it does this it also outputs a lot of white spaces (returns). I've tried to remove them with \n, \t, \r but obviously I don't know where to put the code to make it work. Can you help me with this?

Comment: probably right before the return() call...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try:**

```
<?php
function get_excerpt_by_id($post_id){
$the_post = get_post($post_id); //Gets post ID
$the_excerpt = $the_post->post_content; //Gets post_content to be used as a basis for the excerpt
$excerpt_length = 35; //Sets excerpt length by word count
$the_excerpt = strip_tags(strip_shortcodes($the_excerpt)); //Strips tags and images
$words = explode(' ', $the_excerpt, $excerpt_length + 1);
if(count($words) > $excerpt_length) :
array_pop($words);
array_push($words, '…');
$the_excerpt = implode(' ', $words);
endif;
$the_excerpt = '<p>' . $the_excerpt . '</p>';
// LOOK HERE
$the_excerpt = str_replace("\r", "", $the_excerpt); // Replace carriage returns
$the_excerpt = str_replace("\n", "", $the_excerpt); // Replace new lines
// .. etc
return $the_excerpt;
}
?>
```

Comment: just to add to your answer $the_excerpt = str_replace( array( "\n" , "<br\>" , "<br />" , "\r"), '', the_excerpt());

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
    function get_excerpt_by_id($post_id){
       $the_post = get_post($post_id); //Gets post ID
       $the_excerpt = $the_post->post_content; //Gets post_content to be used as a basis for the excerpt
       $the_excerpt = apply_filters('the_excerpt', $the_excerpt);
       return $the_excerpt;
    }
?>
```